# How to solve Route replacement error in using the changeTarget command?

Tags: python, sumo

I'm trying to make all the vehicles stay on my simulation, the simulation tries to create a contamination program in which the red cars contaminate the green ones until every car is contaminated.

For now what I want is to redirect the car when it's on the end of its route to a new end, to achieve that I'm using the `getRoute` and `getRouteIndex` functions to know if the vehicle is at the end of the route and using `changeTarget` to set the new route, which theoretically should be created by the command. However, an error code keeps showing up: `traci.exceptions.TraCIException : Route replacement failed for 13`

The vehicle '13' is the first one to leave the simulation.
I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3, SUMO 0.32.0 and using the os, sys, optparse, subprocess, random, math libraries.

Here is the rest of the code if it is of any help:

```
def pitagoras(x,y):                     #calculo simples da hipotenusa
    pitagoras = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    return pitagoras

def distancia(veh1,veh2):      #calculo simples da distancia de 2 veiculos
    distancia = pitagoras(traci.vehicle.getPosition(str(veh1))[0] - traci.vehicle.getPosition(str(veh2))[0],traci.vehicle.getPosition(str(veh1))[1] - traci.vehicle.getPosition(str(veh2))[1])
    return distancia

def get_options():
    opt_parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    opt_parser.add_option("--nogui", action="store_true",
                         default=False, help="run the commandline version of sumo")
    options, args = opt_parser.parse_args()
    return options


def separacao(vetor):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    vetor_puro=[]
    vetor_contaminado=[]
    for i in traci.vehicle.getIDList(): #se o carro nao estava na simulacao antes ele coloca ele no vetor dos nao contaminados e poe sua cor inicial como verde
        if i not in vetor:
            vetor.append(i)
            traci.vehicle.setColor(i,(0,255,0,255))
    for i in vetor:
        if traci.vehicle.getColor(i) == (255,0,0,255): #se o carro eh vermelho e nao ja esta no vetor contaminado adiciona-se ele ao vetor contamindo
            if i not in vetor_contaminado:
                    vetor_contaminado.append(i)
        else:                                           #se o carro nao eh vermelho e ja nao esta no vetor dos puros adiciona-se ele ao vetor dos puros
            if i not in vetor_puro:
                vetor_puro.append(i)
    matriz_carros = 0
    matriz_carros = [vetor_puro,vetor_contaminado]
    return matriz_carros



def contaminacao(veh1,veh2,matriz_carros): #passa a cor dos contaminados para os nao contaminados
    if distancia(str(veh1),str(veh2)) < 30:
        traci.vehicle.setColor(str(veh2),(255,0,0,255))



# contains TraCI control loop
def run():
    step = 0
    vetor_puro = []
    vetor_contaminado = []
    matriz_contaminados = []
    matriz_contaminados_2 = []
    while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
        traci.simulationStep()
        step += 1  
        if step > 6 and step < 12:  #da tempo para entrarem carros na simulacao
            j = 0
            i = 0
            k = 0
            carros_totais = []
            carros_totais = (traci.vehicle.getIDList()) 
            for i in carros_totais:
                traci.vehicle.setColor(i,(0,255,0,255))
            print(carros_totais)
            traci.vehicle.setColor(carros_totais[1],(255,0,0,255))
            matriz_carros = separacao(carros_totais)
            print(matriz_carros)
        if step >= 12:      #comeca a contaminacao
            atualizada = traci.vehicle.getIDList()
            for i in atualizada:
                print("carro")
                print(i)
                print("index da rota")
                print(traci.vehicle.getRouteIndex(str(i)))
                print(len(traci.vehicle.getRoute(str(i))))
                if traci.vehicle.getRouteIndex(str(i)) == (len(traci.vehicle.getRoute(str(i))) - 2):
                    novo_destino = random.choice(traci.edge.getIDList())
                    traci.vehicle.changeTarget(str(i),str(novo_destino))
            for i in matriz_carros[1]:
                for j in matriz_carros[0]:
                    if j not in matriz_carros[1]:
                        contaminacao(str(i),str(j),matriz_carros)
            print(carros_totais)
            matriz_carros = separacao(carros_totais)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the new destination is reachable from the last edge of the old route?

Comment: From what i saw on netedit tool, it is guaranteed to reach any other lanes from the last edge.

Comment: Can you share your scenario?

Comment: Of course, how can i do that?

Comment: The easiest way for me would be if you open a ticket here https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues and attach it as a zip.

Comment: Done, here is the link : https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/6130 , sorry for the delay it has been some difficult days.